# mssql table multi foreign key cascade

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, cascade

I'm confident that this is possible but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

What I have created is a user history MSSQL table to hold the changes made to a user and by whom. This table contains two foreign keys which reference my other table (User) - one fkey for the affected user and the other fkey for the user making the changes.

What I need is for any changes to the (User) table to cascade and update the corresponding entries in this new table.

The fields in the new table (User_History) are as follows (Each user is identified by two fields):

```
Affected_User_House_Id  - int
Affected_User_Id - int
Modified_By_User_House_Id - int
Modified_By_User_Id – int
Modification_Date - datetime
ModificationMade - ntext
```

Each field is a primary key except for ‘ModificationMade’. The field ‘Modification_Date’ is accurate down to 1 second.
The problem I am having is creating said cascade.
I have tried running the following T-SQL code:

```
ALTER TABLE [User_History] WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_User_History_User] FOREIGN KEY([Affected_User_House_Id], [Affected_User_Id])
REFERENCES [User] ([User_House_Id], [User_ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [User_History] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_History_User]
GO

ALTER TABLE [User_History]  WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_User_History_User_ModifiedBy] FOREIGN KEY([Modified_By_User_House_Id], [Modified_By_User_Id])
REFERENCES [User] ([User_House_Id], [User_ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [User_History] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_History_User_ModifiedBy]
GO
```

This T-SQL gave me the following error:

```
*'User' table saved successfully
'User_History' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_User_History_User_ModifiedBy'.  
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_User_History_User_ModifiedBy' on table 'User_History' may     cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or     modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.*
```

The code works if I remove the second “ON UPDATE CASCADE” the however that will mean the values in the fields “Modified_By_User_House_Id” and “Modified_By_User_Id” will not be updated to match their referenced values in the User table.

I am at a lost as to how to acomplish this goal.

Comment: Have you tried adding `ON DELETE NO ACTION` to the second constraint?

Comment: you'll need to pick one that gets enforced and enforce the other one some other way, if at all.  SQL Server can't enforce both with cascades, as you're finding.  It's because both FKs point back to the same parent, it can only cascade from one FK to a parent.

Comment: Crazy thing is that even purely `on delete cascade on update no action` still fails in MS SQL. I think not a single other engine shoots their own foot in such a *double-link to const id* scenario.  http://dbfiddle.uk/mznMiGC5  ooops! But then  http://dbfiddle.uk/91kqbfPL and http://dbfiddle.uk/vi-ddKAw and http://dbfiddle.uk/DOUZcRNi and http://dbfiddle.uk/yafshCaT etc.  I was hit by the same limitation trying to implement simple messaging. Yes, i can write triggers, but declarative SQL is always better than imperarive SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify a single cascade. Here's an attempt to simulate multiple cascades with two triggers:

```
create table TabA (
    ID1 int not null,
    ID2 int not null,
    _RowID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    constraint PK_TabA PRIMARY KEY (ID1,ID2),
    constraint UQ_TabA__RowID UNIQUE (_RowID)
)
go
create table TabB (
    ID1a int not null,
    ID2a int not null,
    ID1b int not null,
    ID2b int not null,
    constraint PK_TabB PRIMARY KEY (ID1a,ID2a,ID1b,ID2b)
)
```

They're simpler than your tables, but hopefully close enough. We need an immutable identifier in `TabA`, and obviously the `ID`s aren't it, since the whole point is to cascade changes to them. So I've added `_RowID`.

It would be nice to implement at least a real foreign key and just simulate the cascade behaviour on top of that, but some simple reflection will demonstrate that there's always a point where the FK would be broken. So we simulate it:

```
create trigger FK_TabB_TabA on TabB
after insert,update
as
    set nocount on
    if exists (
        select
            *
        from
            inserted i
                left join
            TabA a
                on
                    i.ID1a = a.ID1 and
                    i.ID2a = a.ID2
                left join
            TabA b
                on
                    i.ID1b = b.ID1 and
                    i.ID2b = b.ID2
        where
            a._RowID is null or
            b._RowID is null)
    begin
        declare @Error varchar(max)
        set @Error = 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the Foreign Key constraint "FK_TabB_TabA". The conflict occurred in database "'+DB_NAME()+'", table "dbo.TabB".'
        RAISERROR(@Error,16,0)
        rollback
    end
```

And then the cascading update:

```
create trigger FK_TabB_TabA_Cascade on TabA
after update
as
    set nocount on

    ;with Updates as (
        select
            d.ID1 as OldID1,
            d.ID2 as OldID2,
            i.ID1 as NewID1,
            i.ID2 as NewID2
        from
            inserted i
                inner join
            deleted d
                on
                    i._RowID = d._RowID
    )
    update b
    set
        ID1a = COALESCE(u1.NewID1,ID1a),
        ID2a = COALESCE(u1.NewID2,ID2a),
        ID1b = COALESCE(u2.NewID1,ID1b),
        ID2b = COALESCE(u2.NewID2,ID2b)
    from
        TabB b
            left join
        Updates u1
            on
                b.ID1a = u1.OldID1 and
                b.ID2a = u1.OldID2
            left join
        Updates u2
            on
                b.ID1b = u2.OldID1 and
                b.ID2b = u2.OldID2
    where
        u1.OldID1 is not null or
        u2.OldID1 is not null
go
```

Some simple inserts:

```
insert into TabA (ID1,ID2)
values (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)
go
insert into TabB (ID1a,ID2a,ID1b,ID2b)
values (1,1,2,2)
```

Then the following gets an error. Not quite like a built in FK violation, but close enough:

```
insert into TabB (ID1a,ID2a,ID1b,ID2b)
values (1,1,2,3)
--Msg 50000, Level 16, State 0, Procedure FK_TabB_TabA, Line 28
--The INSERT statement conflicted with the Foreign Key constraint "FK_TabB_TabA". The conflict occurred in database "Flange", table "dbo.TabB".
--Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
--The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

This is the update that we wanted to be able to perform:

```
update TabA set ID2 = ID2 + 1
```

And we query the FK table:

```
select * from TabB
```

Result:

```
ID1a        ID2a        ID1b        ID2b
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           2           3
```

So the update cascaded.

---

Why you can't use real FKs:

You want to have cascading updates. That means that the ID values in `TabA` are going to change to a new value that doesn't currently exist (caveat - we're excluding situations where 2n rows swap their identity values) - otherwise, the primary key constraint will be broken by this update.

As such, we know that the new key value will not yet exist. If we were to attempt cascading updates using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger (to update the child table before the parent) then the new values we attempt to update to in `TabB` do not yet exist. Alternately, if we attempt to do cascading updates using an `AFTER` trigger - well, we're too late. The FK constraint has already prevented the update.

I suppose you *could* implement an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that inserts the new rows as "duplicates", updates the children, then deletes the old rows. In such a circumstance, I think you could have real FKs. But I don't want to try writing that trigger to be right in all circumstances (e.g where you have three rows being updated. Two swap their ID values and the other creates a new ID)

Comment: I really like this idea, it gives me everything I want but I do wonder if some of it is unnecessary. You say a real foreign key with simulated cascade behaviour would eventually break; can you give an example scenario?

Comment: @user1625159 - I've added a section at the bottom explaining my initial thinking away from real FKs.

Comment: I understand now. My thinking was that the trigger could turn off FKey constraint checks while its cascading the update. I guess this cannot be done with MSSQL?

Comment: @user1625159 - No. Some database systems (Oracle, I think, maybe others) let you declare some constraints with deferred checking, and the checks only happen when the transaction commits. SQL Server doesn't offer such an option - any constraints which are enabled are enforced at statement boundaries.

Comment: Many thanks for this suggestion and the explanation, I will definitely be using it. I gave you a tick.

Comment: This explanation still doesn't explain why `on delete cascade` fails. https://dbfiddle.uk/mznMiGC5 The column would never be changed after inserted, it is `identity` (for the test's sake; in real DB it would be app-provided but still never change; and i wish MS SQL had before-triggers to enforce non-updatibility on column level). So how can `DELETE` cascading lead to any problems here??? And, if it could, no trigger-emulated cascading would've fix it, would it? Also https://dbfiddle.uk/91kqbfPL and https://dbfiddle.uk/vi-ddKAw and https://dbfiddle.uk/DOUZcRNi and https://dbfiddle.uk/yafshCaT

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321843) knowledge base article, this error message occurs when "a table cannot appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement."

Since you have two paths coming from the same table, a possible workaround may involve creating a new key on the parent table and creating a single foreign key on the child (`[Affected_User_House_Id], [Affected_User_Id], [Modified_By_User_House_Id], [Modified_By_User_Id]`). This however, will likely create a lot of overhead. As a last resort, you can use triggers to enforce the relational integrity.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was nice to know why I was having such an issue getting this to work.