# Have table be a FK three times to main table - error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to wrap my head around why I cannot do the following, or why it is not working.

I have a table for **Users**, within the table I have the option for a user to choose up to three roles all named role1, role2, role3.

I figured I could make a single **Roles** table, that would contain all the possible roles (ID + rolename), but whenever I try to add a FK relationship linking role2/role3 to the **Roles** table ID, I get an error saying I *cannot create the foreign key ___ with the SET CASCADE referential*. This works fine when doing it for role1, but adding additional FK's for role2/role3 does not work.

Do I need to make a table of **Roles** for each instance, or why does this not work? I can tell that this could be an issue (just instinct), but I can't pinpoint it in my head... I am still new databasing as well.

Thank you!

Using: SQL Server Studio Management 2012

**EDIT:**
In this image, both role2 and champ2/3 give me errors when I try to have the relationships `delete`/`update` set on `cascade`, when it is set on `no action` it works fine however
[image]

Comment: Could you post your DDL ?

Comment: I haven't seen your query but what I assume from your question is, you are trying to create multiple foreign key with `CASCADE`, which is not allowed. Similar problem has been addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352256/mssql-table-multi-foreign-key-cascade).

Comment: added a diagram for reference! If I set the additional FK to `no action` it seems to not complain, but if a Role is deleted I would like to occur amongst both roles, like cascade does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occurring because of multiple cascade path. i am giving you two suggestions as per your question.

**Option1:**

This is not the good way to design the database...i suggest you to make a link table between the **ROLES** table and **USERS** table. you can store the Roles along with the UserID in the link table to overcome this problem

First Table

```
RoleID(PK) RoleName
```

Second table (Link Table)

```
LinkID(PK) UserID RoleID
```

Third Table

```
UserID(PK) UserName
```

1. First table and second table will have one to many relationship via RoleID.
2. Third table and second table will have one to many relationship via UserID.

**Option2:**

if you do not want to make link table then you have another option. you can make FK between the **ROLES** table and **USERS** without including **CASCADING UPDATE** and **CASCADE DELETE** and then you can handle the update and deletion using **TRIGGERS**

Comment: from my opinion I find he Option 1 the best way to go. But for option 2 I think even triggers he could not delete or update unless he makes no foreign key constraints definition for the users table

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd In case of triggers you need not to define any **FK**. you can do the task with **TRIGGERS** only. Define the **UPDATE** and **DELETE** triggers on **PARENT** table. Whenever deletion/updation takes place you can pick the deleted/updated RoleID from the SQL Server's default **deleted/inserted** table and then trigger can delete/update the entry correspond to deleted/updated RoleID in child table.

Comment: If I did option one, would that make three separate rows for a user if someone had three roles? Or would I be able to keep it as one row?

Comment: Anyone duct-tape way to keep them all in one row, or nah?

Comment: using Option 1 its impossible to do...
is it your mandatory need that you have to keep them all in one row?

Answer (score 0):

From your request it is impossible cause it may result cycles or multiple cascade paths.

```
CREATE TABLE ROLES (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE USERS (ID_USER INT, ROLE1 INT, ROLE2 INT, ROLE3 INT);

ALTER TABLE USERS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_R1 FOREIGN KEY (ROLE1) REFERENCES ROLES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE USERS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_R2 FOREIGN KEY (ROLE2) REFERENCES ROLES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE USERS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_R3 FOREIGN KEY (ROLE3) REFERENCES ROLES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If you try to execute just the **FK_R1**, it excecutes with success, but if you try to execute the second one besides the first one then it gives error.

explanation too easy, if the rdbms allows you to create **FK_R1** an **FK_R2** and by time you waned to delete the row from the mother table by DELETE statement, that will result in dumb data in the other referencing Cols.

Comment: Could you explain this further, or dumb it down for me? When I set the second and third option to `no action` it does not give me an issue, why does this throw an error when I try to do it with cascade? I ask this as if a Role from the Roles table is removed, I know that sometimes a delete will not occur due to the Server not allowing null children which then cancels my delete operation.